# Power BI - Detect Outliers and the best way to show it

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have my data like this,

```
Country     Value
USA          100
USA          120
USA          200
UK           200
UK           210
UK           400
```

I need to detect outliers for each country and show them in a visual.
I tried using the box plots (Country Vs Value), but I have nearly around 3M rows and it crashes. Any suggestions on how to solve this issue in a better way would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power BI has [anomaly detection](https://radacad.com/anomaly-detection-in-power-bi) since the [November 2020 update](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/anomaly-detection-preview/).

If it's choking on the size of the data, then it might help to define an aggregated table where you group it at the level needed for the visual so that, e.g., you only have as many rows as countries for your example.

Answer (score 1):

In case your data per country has a normal distribution. It may help to filter on the rows where the  value  column Z-score is higher than 3 times the Average of the data for country(i).

The Z-score measures how many standard deviations the data point is away from its mean (X̄). Then once identified the outliers for each country, you may draw a scatter plot, showing data points in the same plot, with a different color by country.